# Can we deploy Azure SQL Database to a private virtual network and why?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Can we deploy Azure SQL Database (not managed instance) to a private virtual network and why? I think it is perfectly possible to do it in AWS,  to deploy the RDS instance into VPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure’s current solution for this is [Private Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview). This will give you a private IP in the subnet of your choosing for the Azure SQL DB logical server. From there you can disable public traffic to SQL and your database is only accessible over your private network.

In my opinion there’s still a gap in securing the network further - NSGs on that subnet and the SQL firewalls don’t apply to the private endpoint - so you’re limited to only restricting traffic from the source to that private endpoint.